# Scala: for-loop with getOrElse doesn't work?

Tags: scala, for-loop, functional-programming

I want to find the values to a list of keys in a map. If the map doesn't contain the key, it should return an empty List.

```
val keys = List("a", "b", "c")
val kv = Map("a" -> List(0,1), "b" -> List(1))
```

`val result: List[List[Int]] = List( List(0,1), List(1), List())`

My approach was the following:

```
val result = for (key <- keys; value <- kv.getOrElse(key, List.empty[Int])) yield value
```

But that just returns `result  : List[Int] = List(0, 1, 1)`

And `kv.filterKeys(word => keys.contains(word)).values.toList` doesn't return the empty list either (obviously)

So my question is: Why does the getOrElse function not seem to work properly or how could I do it better?

Comment: You're scanning for multiple keys, you want to return an empty list for each key that's not available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the equivalent of a `flatMap`, so the empty list is getting returned, it's just being flattened out.  You want to just use a `map`:

```
keys map {kv.getOrElse(_, List())}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to using `for-yield`, just change the `value` generator to an assignment:

```
for (key <- keys; value = kv.getOrElse(key, List.empty[Int])) yield value
```

which is equivalent to:

```
for (key <- keys) yield kv.getOrElse(key, List.empty[Int])
```

For more details about `for-yield`, here's a [Scala doc](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html).